# How do I not show the chatter post to another profile

Tags: chatter, administration, profile

I have this scenario
1. User1 belonging to Profile1 created a chatter post on Account1
2. User2 belonging to Profile2 should NOT be able to see that chatter post for Account1

As an admin, how do I enable this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think thats possible with standard SF functionality as the Visbility has only 2 options.

- Internal Only(All SF users with Platform license)
- All with Access(This can also span community users)

That being said, what you can do is create a Private chatter group and when you can tag that record in that private chatter group, thus people who are members of that chatter group can see the post. Its probably not the best solution out there, but works for our use case.

Source : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_group_about.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F&type=5